# Spark SQL: set avro Schema option using SQL API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, databricks

I'm trying to read **Avro** data from **Spark SQL** using **SQL API**.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE episodes
USING com.databricks.spark.avro
OPTIONS (path "/tmp/episodes.avro")
```

Is it possible to set avroSchema (**.avsc** file) option like in Scala API?

Example:

```
spark
  .read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .option("avroSchema", new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("user.avsc")).toString)
  .load("/tmp/episodes.avro").show()
```

Comment: If you have possibility to create Hive table, you can create Hive external table and provide link to avro schema:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
      STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
      OUTPUTFORMAT
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
      LOCATION 'PATH TO DATA'
      TBLPROPERTIES (
        'avro.schema.url'='PATH TO AVRO SCHEMA'
      )
;

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer might be helpful to someone who are working on a local machine or learners new to Pyspark. If you are working in Pycharm IDE, it doesn't offer you a method to include Scala or Java dependencies. Spark AVRO doesn't come bundled with Apache Spark. So we need to configure some Java System Variables.

> Go to Spark package where you install Spark.--> spark folder looks for
> conf --> spark-defaults.conf --> edit the file by adding the below
> line at the bottom of the conf file.

```
 > spark.jars.packages      org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.5
```